# Phone number field formatting

Tags: field-update

In contact object, I have phone number field which is type of Phone. The current value is 8767876541. The problem is it is not displaying in correct format. The format which I am looking out is (876)787-6541 . When I click on that field by manually its getting formatted into expected way. the problem is I have 2000+ contacts with wrong format and I want to update all of them through some code.

So I tried the below code for one record to see if that updates the Phone field in correct format.

List myobjects = [ Select Id,Name,Phone From contact where Id='0033600000LMk8M'];
for( Contact myobject : myobjects )
{
    myobject.Phone = '2159003935' ;
}

update myobjects;

But it didn't help me to make the phone number into correct format

I checked it through some stack exchange questions and the answer is showing as

" Any entry of phone numbers through the API does not receive formatting."

Any solution on this please

Comment: Can you link to the question and answer you are referring to in your question please.

Comment: @ Dave Humm : This is the link which I referred.  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17118/need-a-formula-to-update-unformatted-phone-numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below method on the phone number:

```
static String formatPhoneNum (String fixedPhone) {
    fixedPhone = '(' + fixedPhone.substring(0, 3) + ') ' + fixedPhone.substring(3, 6) + '-' + fixedPhone.substring(6);
    return fixedPhone;
    }
```

Comment: Can you let me know how I can add it in my code please

Comment: It worked...  Below is my code                                                    List<Contact> myobjects = [ Select Id,Name,Phone From contact where Id='*************'];
for( Contact myobject : myobjects )
{
    String fixedPhone;
    fixedPhone = myobject.Phone;
    fixedPhone= '(' + fixedPhone.substring(0, 3) + ') ' + fixedPhone.substring(3, 6) + '-' + fixedPhone.substring(6);
    system.debug('fixedPhone ::' + fixedPhone);
    myobject.Phone = fixedPhone ;
    
}

update myobjects;